# Unable to return array values after being added into the array

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express

I am fetching several ids from the array field stored in mongodb database and I am storing those values into some constant variable as an array.Now I am using map function to iterate through array and based on those  ids I am performing some query operation inside map function and when I am getting the result I am storing it inside new array and then I am trying to return that new array to the users.

Below is my code:

```
 const data = await userSchema.findOne({_id:objectId,active:true});
 const hubIdArray = data.hubs; //Here storing all the ids getting from db array field  

 const hubs = []; //Storing values here after performing query opseration inside map function
 hubIdArray.map(async (hubId) => {
    const hub = await hub_schema.findOne({id:hubId});
    hubs.push(hub);
    console.log(hubs);  // Here I am getting the hubs array.
 })
 console.log('Out',hubs); // But here its returning an empty array
 return res.send(hubs);
```

Why I am getting the array inside map function but not outside the map function even if I have declared an empty hubs array outside the map function.Someone let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map` function is `async` so basically your `console.log('Out',hubs)` runs before your retrieval was completed.
The easiest way to solve this is to change the `map` to a standard `for` loop.

```
const hubs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < hubIdArray.length; i++) {
    const hub = await hub_schema.findOne({id:hubIdArray[i]});
    hubs.push(hub);
    console.log(hubs); 
}
console.log('Out',hubs); 
return res.send(hubs);
```

Comment: Please note that running with this for loop will run the `findOne`s one after another, and not in parallel as your example did. If you need to run this in parallel then you can change back to `map` and collect all the promises and await to `promise.all`